# Spells hand motions in Harry Potter universe

Tags: harry-potter, spells

What is the origin of each hand movement for each spell in the Harry Potter universe?

There is so much information on the Internet about each spell, and for each spell, you can find the way your hand should move while casting it.

However, I do not remember any professor specifying how to move your hand in the book, and in the movies, only when the students are taught Wingardium Leviosa in the first year.

Here's an example, one of the most remembered spells is the unlocking spell 'Alohomora'.

In the [Harry Potter wiki](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Unlocking_Charm), from one end, you can see a GIF of Hermione simply pointing at a door from the first movie, and on the other hand, you can see a drawing that they claim is the way you should move your wand while casting it. (If you think that this source is not reliable for that information, I'm sorry.)

[image: screenshot of HP wiki sidebar]

Of course, the second symbol is from the computer game. Obviously, for the game, they would need to invent a specific motion for each spell.

So given that you don't really get any information from any platform (movies, books, games), where do people get this information?

Answer (score 1):

With the wiki, you can easily find the source for an image by clicking on it and hovering over "More Info" in the right corner.

The first image is from [The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 1](https://pottermore.fandom.com/wiki/The_Standard_Book_of_Spells,_Grade_1) on the old Pottermore:

[image: The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 1]

See also [Pottermore Wiki: Unlocking Spell](https://pottermore.fandom.com/wiki/Unlocking_Spell).

The second image comes from the mobile game [Harry Potter: Hogwarts Mystery](https://www.bluemoongame.com/harry-potter-hogwarts-mystery/guides/lessons/year-1/charms/unlocking-charm-alohomora/).

Comment: I can see it's coming from there. I am asking if any of this is official by J.K Rowling in any platform or is it randomly generated somehow for the games.

Answer (score -1):

The first image in the pic is from pottermore Playstation game wich is not accurate bc it is from a game and just for tha game and if  it was it wouldn't show another wand motion for the levitation charm instead of swish and flick wich is the right wand motion and the second image is also from a game but this time it is a mobile game and the best and most accurate source for wand movements is simply the movies itself

Comment: Hi, Rose, and thank you for trying again to answer the question.  Your  identification of the images is useful, but the question is actually asking if the game designers have a canonical source for these patterns, or if everyone is just making it up.  The details about casting Alohomora are just a specific example for a general question.